# React player. Как настроить плеер так, чтобы он не выключался после перехода на другую страницу?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hook

Мне необходимо, чтобы плейлист из soundcloud играл не прекращаясь, так же после перехода на другую страницу. Сам проект достаточно большой, так что я кину только код этого компонента

```
import React, { Component, PureComponent} from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const WidjetPlayer = () => {
    return (
        <div className='player-wrapper'>
            <ReactPlayer
                className='react-player'
                url="https://soundcloud.com/pro100mail/sets/radio-1"
                width="1000"
                  pip={true}
                  stopOnUnmount={false}
                playsinline={false}
                
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default WidjetPlayer;
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант вынести плеер над роутами. То есть в коде:

```
<WidjetPlayer/>
<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter>
```